# Настройка django и virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Установлены python 2.7 и python 3.2, в виртуальном окружении установлен python 3.4. По 127.0.0.1:8000 сайт работает.

В логах выдает ошибку:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding ImportError: No module named encodings

Структура проекта:

```
/var/www/myproject

..../static_content

..../src

......../myproject

............manage.py

............/myproject

...............django.wsgi  (использую сейчас)  

...............settings.py       

...............urls.py

...............wsgi.py (был изначально)   

.../logs

.../env

......../bin
.............activate
.............activate.csh
.............activate.fish
.............django-admin
.............django-admin.py
.............easy_install
.............easy_install-3.4
.............pip
.............pip3
.............pip3.4
.............python -> python3.4
.............python3 -> python3.4
.............python3.4 -> /usr/local/opt/python-3.4.3/bin/python3.4

......../include

......../lib

......../docs
```

django.wsgi:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys, site
site.addsitedir('/var/www/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/sitepackages')
sys.path.append('/var/www/myproject/env/bin')
sys.path.append('/var/www/myproject/src/myproject')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
```

Update:
Теперь сайт открывается по localhost, но выдает ошибку:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /

main.html

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.1/
Django Version:     1.7.7
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

main.html

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py in find_template, line 136
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.4.2
Python Path:    

['/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/var/www/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/sitepackages',
 '/var/www/myproject/env/bin',
 '/var/www/myproject/src/myproject']
```

Т.е. версия django ипользуется не та, что в виртуальном окружении

Comment: что выдает pip freeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys, site
site.addsitedir('/var/www/myproject/env/lib/python3.4/sitepackages')
sys.path.append('/var/www/myproject/env/bin')
sys.path.append('/var/www/myproject/src/myproject')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

virtualenv = os.path.join('/var/www/myproject/env/', 'bin', 'activate')
try:
    exec(compile(open(virtualenv).read(), virtualenv, 'exec'), dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except:
    pass

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, апач увидел джанговский сайт, запускается пока с ошибками. Осталась проблема: внутри виртуального окружения используется django 1.8.3, а на сайте пишется, что django version 1.7.7, т.е. при запуске через wsgi + апач используется установленный в системе django 1.7.7, а не тот, что в виртуальном окружении. Не подскажете, как это исправить?

Comment: Мне кажется у вас ошибка в 3 строке, хотя это не точно, проверте существует ли эта директория, насколько я помню она называется site-packeges.